# Determine whether it is summer or winter month for france android

Tags: java, android, timezone

How to determine whether current month is a summer or winter from GMT date.

Suppose we are in may, how to determine if may is a summer month or winter month for the current year.

```
DateTimeZone franceZone = DateTimeZone.ForId("Europe/France");

DateTimeZone localZone = DateTimeZone.SystemDefault;
ZonedDateTime utc = new ZonedDateTime(2014, 05, 15, 9, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.CEST);
ZonedDateTime france = new ZonedDateTime(CEST.ToInstant(), franceZone);
Console.WriteLine(france.LocalDateTime);
```

Comment: What have you tried?  A little code on your part will provide insight for others so they me be able to help.

Comment: well check updates please

Comment: How do you define winter and summer? Like astronomers? Like meteorologists? Like ... ?

Comment: @Dimitri Do mean summer or winter in the sense of seasons, or do you mean [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two arrayslists
 1- Summer months 2- Winter months

When you retrieve the month value from GMT date run a check through the arraylist to see which array the value matches.

```
for (String s : arrayList)
    if (s.equals(value)){
 season= winter
}
```

Maybe something like that pseudo code

Comment: This will not work as season boundaries do not fall on month boundaries.  For instance, June is both a spring and summer month.  The day of the month is also crucial.